# Why does this stringstream fail when parsing into double?

Tags: c++, stringstream, libc++

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
        size_t x, y;
        double a = std::stod("1_", &x);
        double b = std::stod("1i", &y);

        std::cout << "a: " << a << ", x: " << x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "b: " << b << ", y: " << y << std::endl;

        std::stringstream s1("1_");
        std::stringstream s2("1i");

        s1 >> a;
        s2 >> b;

        std::cout << "a: " << a << ", fail: " << s1.fail() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "b: " << b << ", fail: " << s2.fail() << std::endl;
}
```

I want to parse a double and stop when an invalid character is hit. Here I try to parse `"1_"` and `"1i"`, both of which should give me the double with value: `1`.

here is my output:

```
a: 1, x: 1
b: 1, y: 1
a: 1, fail: 0
b: 0, fail: 1
```

So the `stod` function worked as expected, however the stringstream method did not. It makes no sense to me that 2 standard methods of parsing double, both in the standard library would give different results?

*Why does the stringstream method fail when parsing*: `"1i"`?

Edit:

this appears to give different results for some people. My compiler info is the following:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Edit2:

Is this a bug with libc++, or is the specification just vague about what counts as valid parsing for a double?

Comment: I does not fail.

Comment: @J.Doe I printed `s2.fail()` and it printed 1... surely that means it failed

Comment: Then you are using different code than shown here.

Comment: @J.Doe `std::cout << "b: " << b << ", fail: " << s2.fail() << std::endl;`. Are you saying you ran my code snippet and got different results? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes. Whats to elaborate? Both stringstreams extract the `'1'` and interprete it as `double`.

Comment: When I run your code snippet exactly the way you posted it, the last line is `b: 1, fail: 0`. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as a problem that can't be reproduced.

Comment: @JosephSible what compiler are you using? I am using clang... on macos

Comment: @TheoWalton Compiler and version, standard library implementation and version?

Comment: I'm using Clang 3.8.1 on Linux.

Comment: @J.Doe edited to show compiler info

Comment: [Here's the repro](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0qZ3Vd2nWThsE2Z6). Looks like the difference might be libc++ vs. libstdc++ if it's working on Linux and not MacOS.

Comment: I am using ```clang++-6.0``` and ```libstdc++```, the second one succeeded no matter what version of ```C++``` is used.

Comment: Yeah, this is a known libc++ bug.

Comment: @T.C. Do you have a link to a bug report that could be posted as answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [libc++ bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17782). Per [[facet.num.get.virtuals] bullet 3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/facet.num.get.virtuals#3.2.sentence-5), a character is only supposed to be accumulated if it is allowed as the next character of the input field of the conversion specifier determined in stage 1 (`%g` for `double`). Having accumulated `1`, `i` is not allowed, so stage 2 should terminate.

libc++ is accumulating characters indiscriminately until it reaches a non-atom character (it also extended the atoms to include `i`, which is required to parse inf).